# Can Chiral symmetry violating term in lagrangian violate charge conversation?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, electric-current, symmetry, field-theory, symmetry-breaking

The regular Lagrangian is

$\mathcal{L}=\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)\psi$

If we add a chiral violating term

$\mathcal{L}=\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-me^{i\theta\gamma^5})\psi$

For the charge to be conserved it's necessary for the current to satisfy

$\partial_\mu j^\mu=0$

Where $j^\mu=\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi$

To test this identity, we need to write out Dirac equation and conjugated Dirac equation

$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-me^{i\theta\gamma^5})\psi=0$
$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu+me^{-i\theta\gamma^5})\bar{\psi}=0$

If we multiply both by conjugated functions

$\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-me^{i\theta\gamma^5})\psi=0$
$\psi(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu+me^{-i\theta\gamma^5})\bar{\psi}=0$

If we add them

$\bar{\psi}i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi-me^{i\theta\gamma^5}\bar{\psi}\psi+\psi i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\bar{\psi}+me^{-i\theta\gamma^5}\psi\bar{\psi}=0$

If we simplify with product rule

$i\partial_\mu j^\mu=(e^{i\theta\gamma^5}-e^{-i\theta\gamma^5})m\bar{\psi}\psi\ne0$

So it means that charge is not conserved and the Prova equation would have no solutions.

Is my derivation correct or I did something wrong?

Comment: There is a sign mistake with your conjugated Dirac equation. You forgot that $\overline{\gamma^5}=-\gamma^5$ so $\overline{e^{i\theta\gamma^5}}=e^{i\theta\gamma^5}$ (which would be necessary anyways in order to have a real Lagrangian density). This means that the conjugated Dirac equation is rather:$$\bar \psi (-i\gamma \cdot \partial +e^{i\theta\gamma^5}) $$ and in your last line the two terms being the same cancel out.

Comment: @lpz I see, thanks. So, as I can see, in more specific case without $\gamma^5$ in exponential (a tachyon) will have unconserved current.

Comment: The issue then would be to derive the equations of motion. In this case, since the Langrangian density is complex (not real), the principle of least action needs to be amended. It comes to no surprise that Noether’s theorem might be compromised as a result.